# How to retain the checkbox selections in a MultiSelection Listbox?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, checkedlistbox

I have a multiselection listbox with the option style (check boxes to the left).

I have the below code to transfer the selected data to the worksheet (this must be dynamic since the listbox itself is fed by a dynamic named range).

```
Private Sub cmdRun_Click()

Dim i As Integer

i = 0

Do While i < lstProperties.ListCount + 1
    If lstProperties.Selected(i) = True Then
    Sheet7.Cells(i + 1, 1) = lstProperties.List(i)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

It seems like it wants to work but I think when I run the command it is unselecting the list box data after the first loop and therefore only transposing the first selection in the list box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old thread, but it’s the only one I could find on the topic, and it was never solved.

I was having the exact same problem with my userform (only the first selected item in the list is returned to the worksheet, as it appears to deselect the listbox data before looping through the remaining items), but after reading this thread I was able to come up with a solution.

The problem is that the RowSource is a dynamic named range (“FilterData”), and when the first selected item is returned to the worksheet it triggers the workbook to recalculate all formulas, including the formula for your dynamic named range, thus refreshing the listbox RowSource and clearing the selected items before it has a chance to loop through them all.

The solution is to turn off automatic formula calculations before your Do While Loop statement (and turn it back on afterwards... very important) like so:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
Do While i < lstProperties.ListCount
    If lstProperties.Selected(i) = True Then
        Sheet7.Cells(Rw, 1) = lstProperties.List(i)
        Rw = Rw + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateAutomatic
```

Hopefully that helps anyone else looking for a solution to the same problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a separate variable for the row reference so that you can increment it only when an item from the listbox is selected...

```
Private Sub cmdRun_Click()

Dim Rw As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheet7.Columns(1).ClearContents

Rw = 1
i = 0
Do While i < lstProperties.ListCount
    If lstProperties.Selected(i) = True Then
        Sheet7.Cells(Rw, 1) = lstProperties.List(i)
        Rw = Rw + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This makes since, but it still will only add the first selection to the worksheet. It still just feel like it is calling the userform after the first loop and therefore nothing Is selected when it runs the code again.

Comment: The code will always copy any and all selected items to your worksheet starting in Row 1.  If you want to replace any existing results, you'll need to clear the column before you run your code again.  If you want to copy them to the next available row, you'll need to change `Rw = 1` so that you assign the next available row to your variable.

Comment: If I copy the code exactly how you have provided, it will copy the first selected item into row 1 every time. For example if I have list item ABC & DEF selected it will copy ABC to Row 1; if I have just DEF selected it will copy DEF to Row 1. Is it because how I Initialize? `Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

Me.lstProperties.RowSource = "FilterData"

Me.lstStmts.RowSource = "propsNOI"

Me.lstLoans.RowSource = "FilterLoans"

End Sub`

Comment: I edited my post to correct the code name referring to your sheet, and I added a line of code at the beginning to clear the contents of the column before transferring the data to the worksheet.